# Mapbox Directions configure markers

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, geojson

I'm using the Mapbox directions API and leaflet to create an interactive map.

When invoking the directions functionality, everything works great and Mapbox sets a marker for my origin and destination.

By default, it uses a generic marker with A and B respectively. I can't find any documentation on configuring the marker it uses, does anyone have any insights, examples, or suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation seems to focus on featureLayers to make custom pin. I found that markers with custom icon do the job better.

Here is the way I do it:

blueIcon = new L.icon({
    iconUrl: '/img/Bo6.png',
    iconSize:     [75, 75], // size of the icon
    popupAnchor:  [300, -125]
          });

movingMarker = new L.marker([51.5, -54.11],
        {
    "title": "Felix in Space",
    "description": "1718 14th St NW, Washington, DC",
    className: "event-popup-box",
    icon: blueIcon
           });

movingMarker.addTo(themap);